# Disable HTTP module for specific route in MVC web app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, httpmodule

I have an MVC web app which uses an authentication module that was developed in house by the organisation I work for.

A requirement that I am working on at the moment requires a certain user type to access a particular URL without an account, therefore I need to circumvent the authentication on that route only.

Is it possible to conditionally detach an HTTP module based on route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` above the action to be called.